# Расшифровка ID в Access

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, ms-access, visual-studio-2019

имеется БД в которой находятся таблицы "Сотрудники" и "Отделы", в таблице "Сотрудники" в поле "Отдел" имеется ID отдела тип данных(Числовой), а в таблице "Отделы" имеются поля "ID", "Название отдела".

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как ID превратить в название отдела? Пробовал запросами, но там получается только выводить ячейку с названием, а мне нужно вывести ВСЮ таблицу Сотрудники уже с расшифрованным ID, то есть | 6 | ИТ-Отдел|, за место 6 должен появится ИТ-Отдел.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Используйте JOIN в запросе

Comment: Это не то, Join присоединяет таблицу

Comment: Ну так это как раз то что вам нужно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам следует изучить основы SQL-запросов. Подстановка значения по id - это базовая конструкция SQL. Конкретно в вашем случае нужно написать простейший запрос `SELECT` с указанием нужных столбцов и использованием `JOIN`.

```
SELECT
    [Сотрудники].[Фамилия],
    [Сотрудники].[Имя],
    [Сотрудники].[Отчество],
    [Отделы].[Название отдела]
FROM
    [Сотрудники] LEFT JOIN [Отделы] ON [Сотрудники].[Отдел] = [Отделы].[Код];
```

Comment: Спасибо, оказывается и так можно было)